# Suggestion: rename the "icon" tag to "icons"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I think plural works better, and matches existing tags ([applications](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications), [graphic-drivers](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic-drivers), etc.)

Comment: I'm retagging now

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: Update: I can't. It's not allowing a plural. Funnily enough it says to raise on meta which is umm what we've done :P

Comment: Uh... so what now? Maybe delete the tag and then recreate it as the plural version (and then retag the questions)?

Comment: drat, still not leting me :/ it still exitst it thinks [tag:icon]

Comment: <!-- strettttch --> Done.

Comment: @RobertCartaino can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @RobertCartaino ping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`icon` is now [icons](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icons).